# How to create an array combining an object and another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I got an object of values which looks like this

```
const values = {
   volume: {
      length: "3",
      height: "4",
      width: "2"
   }
}
```

and an array with the attribute labels belonging to the values. The array looks like this:

```
const attributes = [
   {
      id: "notImportant",
      label: "notImportantFoo"
   },
   {
      id: "length",
      label: "LengthFoo"
   },
   {
      id: "width",
      label: "WidthFoo"
   },
   {
      id: "height",
      label: "HeightFoo"
   }
]
```

I need to create a new array from all the values with the right label. The result should look like this:

```
const result = [
   {
      label: "LengthFoo",
      reading: "3"
   },
   {
      label: "WidthFoo",
      reading: "4"
   },
   {
      label: "HeightFoo",
      reading: "2"
   }
]
```

I tried to start by mapping all the Object keys of the values but since it is wrapped in another object I couldn't really access it.

Comment: Please don't just tell us that you tried something, actually show what you tried.

Comment: Just giving you an answer only helps you with this specific problem. If we can correct you and show you why/where you went wrong, chances are higher that you learn something. Allowing you to solve the next similar issue yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
const result = attributes.filter(x => x.id in values.volume)
                         .map(x => ({
                             label: x.label,
                             reading: values.volume[x.id]
                         }));
```

What are we doing here?

1. Traversing the array of attributes
2. Skipping values that do not exist in the object ([`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))
3. Creating a projection that contains required data from both attribute definition and the real object ([`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will get you there:

```js
const values = {
  volume: {
    length: "3",
    height: "4",
    width: "2"
  }
};

const attributes = [{
  id: "notImportant",
  label: "notImportantFoo"
}, {
  id: "length",
  label: "LengthFoo"
}, {
  id: "width",
  label: "WidthFoo"
}, {
  id: "height",
  label: "HeightFoo"
}];

const result = Object.entries(values.volume).map(([id, reading]) => ({
  label: attributes.find(v => v.id === id)?.label,
  reading
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile `Array.forEach`, `Object.keys` and `Array.includes` to make it works.

- `Array.forEach` to loop `attributes` array.
- `Object.keys` to get `length`, `width`, `height` properties from `values.volume`.
- `Array.includes` to filter the needed properties only.

You can check my below demo:

```js
const values = {
   volume: {
      length: "3",
      height: "4",
      width: "2"
   }
}

const attributes = [
   {
      id: "notImportant",
      label: "notImportantFoo"
   },
   {
      id: "length",
      label: "LengthFoo"
   },
   {
      id: "width",
      label: "WidthFoo"
   },
   {
      id: "height",
      label: "HeightFoo"
   }
]

var valueKeys = Object.keys(values.volume);

var result = [];
attributes.forEach(item => {
   if (valueKeys.includes(item.id)) {
      result.push({
         label: item.label,
         reading: values.volume[item.id]
      });
   }
});

console.log(result);
```